# ggplot generates jagged/broken lines in specific cases

Tags: r, ggplot2, eps

I recently encountered several cases where the `ggplot` produced jagged lines. In the following example, I generate dense time-course data with the package `fda` and draw two line plots. The first plot gives the black line and the other plot displays the same line except that we use different colors to denote the signs of the values. In the end, I export the plots as eps files and open them in Adobe Illustrator.

```r
# install.packages("fda")
# dir.create("tmp")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(fda)

times_sparse <- seq(0, 10, 0.5)
times <- seq(0, 10, 0.02)

basis <- create.bspline.basis(
  rangeval = c(0, 10), norder = 4,
  breaks = times_sparse
)
nbasis <- basis$nbasis

set.seed(2501)
coeff <- rnorm(nbasis, sd = 0.1)

y <- eval.fd(times, fd(coeff, basis)) |> as.numeric()

dat <- data.frame(t = times, y = y) |>
  mutate(pos = factor((y > 0) * 1, levels = c(1, 0)))

### first plot: 1 colors, smooth lines
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
# ggsave("tmp/line1a.eps", device = "eps",
#        width = 6, height = 6)

### second plot: 2 colors, jagged lines
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t, y = y, color = pos, group = 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
# ggsave("tmp/line1b.eps", device = "eps",
#        width = 6, height = 6)
```

In the screenshots which display the zoomed-in line, we observe that the line in the first plot is smooth, while the line in the second plot is jagged. How can I fix the problem?

[image: line plot 1]  [image: line plot 2]

Here's my system info:

```r
# R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
```

---

*Note*: My goal is to generate an eps/pdf file of something like the second plot from R. Other methods that achieve the same goal are appreciated.

Comment: note there is an important difference between your plots. Your first plot specifies `aes(color = pos, group = 1)`, the second doesn't.

Comment: but having looked at the code on my computer, this is not the issue here. I cannot reproduce it on my machine, everything looks smooth. Must be a device-specific  anti-aliasing problem

Comment: @tjebo you can see it after 800% scale (at my PC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `lineend = "round"` to your `geom_line`

```
ggplot(dat) +
     geom_line(aes(x = t, y = y, color = pos, group = 1), lineend = "round") +
     theme_bw() +
     theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

It will look nice via `export -> save as PDF` and `windows() -> save as...` too.

**An example (2400%):**

[image]

Comment: The `lineend` solution works for me. Thanks a lot! The other two solutions haven't worked on my PC. I am also curious about why the smoothness of the line changes under the minor modification in color setting.